# Tool to automate building a .mailmap file

Tags: git

Is there a tool to automate building a .mailmap file for a git repository?  A lot of the stuff involved in building one can be done automatically after asking some questions (like "which name/email is preferred for person A?"), and a lot more can be done heuristically (like "Is John A. Smith the same person as John Smith?").

I've found it at least a little easier using the command `git log  --format="%aN <%aE>" | sort -u | less`, but building up the file is still more work than it seems like it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SymPy we use [this tool](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/bin/mailmap_check.py). It should generalize nicely to other projects. It also helps keep an AUTHORS file up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [script](https://github.com/greenrd/genmailmap). It currently only guesses canonical email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. `git log --all` should be your starting point. From that point forward, bash piping and scripting is something you should embrace and leverage. Git itself is a bunch of shell scripts anyway - at least at the higher level commands. I've become addicted to looking at them. They can shed a lot of light of what is possible and how to do a lot of interesting things.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standalone solution to the problem, and should easily create a perfect .mailmap, that does a best-effort to map usernames to emails.

https://gist.github.com/AddisonG/ae0572b380af3c51bfdcb738f86bd717

Simply run it like this:

```
cd /my/git/dir/
git shortlog -s -n -e | python3 ~/mailmap.py > .mailmap
```